# Adding Custom Info to Google Maps infowindow

Tags: google-maps

I want to be able to add custom info to the bubbles in google maps. How can this be done using this code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
      type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var locations = [
     ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
     ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
     ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
     ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
     ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
  ];
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What 'custom info' do you want added to the infowindow?

Answer (score 1):

The code you have looks good to me.  There are a number of ways to expand it further, though.  Here's one way:

1. Add more info to your locations variable to include the information that would go in your custom info, e.g., a like a link to an image.

   var locations = [

   ```
   ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4, "http://mysite.com/images/beach.jpg"],

   ...
   ```

   ];
2. Then make a function that will give the info windows the html format they need. It would probably be better that this function pull the html from the actual html, or perhaps one time from the server via ajax, but to keep this example simple I will write the html inline:

   function formatLocation(loc, img) {

   ```
   return "<img src='" + img + "' title=''> <b>" + loc + "</b>";
   ```

   }
3. Then when you set your info window content, just call this function with the required parameters:

   infowindow.setContent(formatLocation(locations[i][0], locations[i][4]));

Hope that helps!